# Mouse sensitivity settings for touch screen in kiosk mode

Tags: 16.04, mouse, google-chrome, chromium, kiosk

I am using Ubuntu as a kiosk system for our company. The kiosk will be in a public location.

I am having a few issues with the mouse (once in kiosk mode). Our kiosk is linked to our website and there are images to choose from, but if the user touches it and moves slightly (like a drag) it would seam as its not working to them. We know why it does this, but I am trying to disable the drag feature so that any click will work no matter what. a

Another issue I am facing, and this may be due to the kiosk settings I have, is that the mouse seems to have a 2 second delay before I can click on anything. For example I will type my email and I will need to wait 2 seconds per click on mouse. I can change these settings if someone can point me in the right direction. [Here is the link](https://github.com/mmihalev/kiosk) to the grub hub of the kiosk I am using in Ubuntu 16.04. with chromnie browser.

Browser settings just in case it can help my case for better understanding.

```
nomaillinks="True"
empty_on_exit="True"
nodownload="True"
browser_reset="True"
disable_config_url="True"
nocontextmenu="True"
fullscreen="True"
kioskmode="True"
enable_browser="True"
nokeys="False"
hide_ppreview="True"
home_url="http://kiosk.bla.bla.bla"
noprint="True"
accept_cookies_session_only="True"
hide_reload="False"
hide_forward="False"
hide_reset="False"
kioskspeeddial="False"
hide_print="True"
hide_addressbar="False"
nomenu="True"
hide_back="False"
hide_zoom="False"
browser_idle="2"
hide_home="False"
custom_user_agent=""
hide_toolbar="False"
hide_find="False"
```

The 2 second delay may be nothing. And it may be caused by the image drag!